# Make Nginx image available in local/private repository for production safe perspective in kubernetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

How can we make nginx image available in my local/private repository in kubernetes?

Lets say i am using nginx image tag version x.x. I have tested it in my dev and test env and want to move it to prod.

What if the image is not present in nginx repository?
Is there a way to pull the x.x version of nginx to our local/private repository?

There is a high risk if the image is not available. So it would be helpful if anyone guide me how we handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have docker installed in your machine, pull docker image

```
$ docker pull nginx:x.x
```

Now, you can't use this local docker image inside Kubernetes. You need to do additional thing

Push this image into your docker registry in cloud.

```
$ docker tag nginx:x.x <your-registry>/nginx:x.x
$ docker push <your-registry>/nginx:x.x
```

And then use `<your-registry>/nginx:x.x` from your registry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This helps